# How to get data from firebase-messaging-sw.js to dart file in Flutter web?

Tags: javascript, flutter, flutter-web

When I'm clicking on background notification, I get a response which I need to use for later so how do I implement this saving, when I click on the background notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to save, if it is needed only when a user clicks a notification. There is `data` field for custom data in [showNotification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/showNotification). `data` will be available in [notificationclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/notificationclick_event) event.

Comment: but how can we get data into the dart file